# Change link trumbnail without meta tag

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

I want to place a share button to my Android App. I have the link to share: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.example.com, but when a share from mobile phone the trumbnail is not this what i need and i can't change it.
I can't use meta tags like meta property="og:image", this is not my page.
How to change this?
Thanks for advice.